# Problem with shellscript crashing after "exec kill -SIGINT"

Tags: shell-script, function

I have modified a shell script i found here:
https://github.com/Slympp/ConanLinuxScript

But im having troubles with the function "conan_stop"
The script just terminates after

```
exec kill -SIGINT $pid
```

The script are sending the kill command successfully but after that it just terminates with no error code or anything.

All the variables in the script are defined earlier in the file.

**Full function**

```
function conan_stop {

pid=$(ps axf | grep ConanSandboxServer-Win64-Test.exe | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')

if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
        echo "[$(date +"%T")][FAILED] There is no server to stop"
else
    if [ "$discordBotEnable" = true ]; then
        echo "[$(date +"%T")][SUCCESS] Discord bot is enabled"
        if [ -n "$botToken" ] && [ -n "$channelID" ]; then
            secLeft=$(($delayBeforeShutdown * 60))

            while [ $secLeft -gt "0" ]; do
                minLeft=$(($secLeft / 60))
                echo "[$(date +"%T")][WAIT] Server will be shut down in $minLeft minutes"
                python3 $discordScript $botToken $channelID "Servern kommer stängas ner om " $minLeft "minuter."
                secLeft=$(($secLeft - 60))
                sleep 60
            done
            python3 $discordScript $botToken $channelID "Servern stängs nu ner."
        else
            echo "[$(date +"%T")][ERROR] No Discord botToken or channelID found"
        fi
    fi

        echo "[$(date +"%T")][SUCCESS] Existing PIDs: $pid"
        exec kill -SIGINT $pid

        isServerDown=$(ps axf | grep ConanSandboxServer-Win64-Test.exe | grep -v grep)
        cpt=0
        while [ ! -z "$isServerDown" ]; do
                echo "[$(date +"%T")][WAIT] Server is stopping..."
                ((cpt++))
                sleep 1
                isServerDown=$(ps axf | grep ConanSandboxServer-Win64-Test.exe | grep -v grep)
        done
        echo "[$(date +"%T")][SUCCESS] Server stopped in $cpt seconds"

        if [ "$discordBotEnable" = true ]; then
                echo "[$(date +"%T")][SUCCESS] Discord bot is enabled"
                if [ -n "$botToken" ] && [ -n "$channelID" ]; then
                        python3 $discordScript $botToken $channelID "Servern stängdes ner efter $cpt sekunder."
                else
                        echo "[$(date +"%T")][ERROR] No Discord botToken or channelID found"
                fi
        fi
fi

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`exec` replaces the shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec) with the given command, like the `exec()` system call. When the command (the `kill`, here) stops, the shell no longer exists, so there's no way for the script to continue.

The two exceptions are 1) when `exec` is given redirections, in which case it just applies them in the current shell, and 2) when the command can't be executed, in which case `exec` gives an error and returns a falsy exit code.

So, `exec kill ...` is almost the same as `kill ... ; exit`. Not exactly the same, but close enough in this case.

Comment: Excellent answer, I totally missed that.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make it better?

Comment: In exception 1 as you descibe, can i redirect the kill command and get the script to continue running after the exec() command?

Comment: @junkyhlm, "Redirection" refers to input/output redirections. See e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html . The thing with `exec` here is that there's no reason to use it at all. Just run the `kill` command as you'd run any other command. That is, remove the `exec`.